# Offline.JS with Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, offline

I am currently working with a Backbone.js application that needs to have offline capabilities.  Currently the UI consists of a list of elements which are clickable.  When clicked a person is "checked in" and the icon on the right changes from Checkin to Undo Checkin.  This allows you to toggle the state of the item.

When I integrate offline.js and I go to a list and then shut off my wifi it works, i can go from UI to UI and the collections load, etc.  However when I tap any list entry to checking or undo checkin then navigate away from that UI to another and back the entire collection of models is just gone.

I can pull it up on my desktop just fine and the collection is there, however it would appear that the changes are not being sent to the server when the connection comes back online, and why would my entire collection just vanish?

The integration I have in place is VERY simple.  I include the offline.js AFTER all of my Backbone dependencies.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/backbone.sync.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/backbone.dualstorage.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/backbone.search.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/offline.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/backbone.routefilter.js"></script>
```

Inside of my application I am initilizing Offline with a few options

```
Offline.options.checkOnLoad = true;
Offline.options.interceptRequests = true;
Offline.options.requests = false;
Offline.options.checks = {xhr: {url: CheckinApp.base_path + '/api/online'}};
```

And that's all I am doing for the integration.  Am I doing something wrong here that would cause my collections to just vanish like they are when an event takes place on the UI?

Comment: I have also tried setting Offline.options.requests = true; thinking maybe that was the issue, but it is still acting the same way.